# change default structure of HATEOAS links

Tags: spring-hateoas

How to change the default structure of Hateoas links:

```
 "first": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/offer/?page=0&size=20"
 },
 "self": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/offer/"
 },
 "next": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/offer/?page=1&size=20"
 },
 "last": {
     "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/offer/?page=2&size=20"
 }
```

to be like this:

```
 {
    "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/offer/?page=0&size=20",
    "rel" : "next",
    "method": "GET"
 },
```